# total number of days from current date if we want to know like after 2 weeks, 3 months , 1 year

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I want to know the total number of days from current date.
if given date is 2 Feb 2018. and i want to calculate number of days after 2 weeks/3 months/1 year. keeping in mind of leap year or not.
Language - python3

Is there any library in python which give me this.

Answer (score 0):

The `dateutil` module has a way to do this very conveniently. Sample code:

```
import datetime
import dateutil

today = datetime.date.today()
delta = dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(years=1, months=3, weeks=2)

desired_date = today + delta
desired_date
```

Output:

```
datetime.date(2019, 5, 16)
```